# final and non-final method parameters, are they treated as different for determining method overloading or overriding?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

Let's have this method in parent class:

```
public void calculateSum(int a, final int b) { }
```

And the child class has:

```
public void calculateSum(int a, int b){ }
```

So is it method overloading or method overriding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's overriding, as the number and type of parameters are the same.

Overloading is when the type or number of parameters changes.

The `final` on the method parameter just instructs the compiler that the variable value (or reference) shouldn't be changed inside the method... this also affects the runtime, as final variables are published safely.

Comment: So int a, and final int a are treated same?

Comment: @shanti, for the purpose of determining method signatures, and therefore whether one method overrides another, yes, `int a` and `final int a` are treated the same.  The direct implications of the `final` qualifier are all internal to the method implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Augusto: Thanks for answering so swiftly.

Answer (score 0):

The child class method is overriding the parent class method. The child class method doesn't define a new set of arguments. The 'final' modifier doesn't affect argument type, just if it can be assigned a new value.

Answer (score 0):

If method signature(which include method name and parameter list) is same along with return type(Assignment Compatible) then it's called overriding. Adding modifier to the parameter does not change the parameter type. So your answer is overriding.